# Added Second search server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search, windows-server-2016

I have a 4 server farm minrole.  Search, Application, Distributed cache, WFE.  I recently added another minrole server and added Search role to it.  It is up and running and added to Farm.  The services on new server are all online and good but I cannot create a new search service application or delete a search service application now.  I re-ran the product configuration a few times but it doesn't seem like I can actually add the new server into the search topology.  In centeral administration everything seems fine otherwise.  Anyone run into this?

Product: SharePoint Enterprise 2016/Windows server Datacenter 2016

Comment: Is there a reason you don't combine DC+FE, App+Search on your 4 existing servers (2 per role)? If your farm is small enough that you only currently have 1 server per role, that seems like your better bet -- also means you don't need to add another server to manage.

Comment: Wasn't sure how big it was going to get.  Also, I have a lot of resources to play with so I wanted to have a true farm to scale and built it that way.  I already added the server into the farm just can't get the search topology to update or create a new search service application using the two.

Comment: as far as I understand the config wizard ran successfully. and now you're trying to create a search service application. how do you create the search service application and what's the error you encounter?